# Opera Add-on windows.create ignores createData dimension and position properties

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opera

It seems that opera ignores `height`, `width`, `top`, `left` properties of the createData parameter.

```
chrome.windows.create({
        type: 'popup',
        focused: false,
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
        top: 100000,
        left: 10000,
        url: 'https://www.google.com'
    })
```

My goal is to create a hidden window.

No matter what values I put there it's always shown in the middle of the screen. I know there is a property `state:'minimized'`, but it's also not working properly, as it will show the window for a split second.

Anyone encountered this and possibly has a workaroud/fix?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Use chrome.windows.update in the callback to set the dimensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the answer, but this approach will show the window for a split second as well as using the state:'minimized'. I am looking for a solution that will not show the window at all. I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: It's the only workaround. BTW did you try and actually see the incorrectly positioned window?

Comment: FWIW, the only other method would be to write a separate utility that hooks window creation and hides the window, the utility will have to be installed separately, see `nativeMessaging` documentation.